# Await appendChild for CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following snippet creates a blue box, then turns it purple. Ideally there would be a smooth transition from blue to purple, but it's practically instant instead. The only way I can achieve this is effect is with a timeout (see the second snippet).

```js
let DOM = document.createElement('div');

DOM.classList.add('box');

document.body.appendChild(DOM);

DOM.classList.add('purple');
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: blue;
 
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.box.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```js
let DOM = document.createElement('div');

DOM.classList.add('box');

document.body.appendChild(DOM);

window.setTimeout(() => {
  DOM.classList.add('purple');
}, 100);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: blue;
 
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.box.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

A timeout seems like a bit of a hacky solution that could fail if the machine was slow or cause excess delay on faster machines. Primarily though, I'm looking for a better solution for this problem. Is there a way to `await` `appendChild` so that the class is added as soon as the element has been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually any value of delay will work here. Even this works:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    DOM.classList.add('purple');
}, 0);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/OscarSaharoy/x46wnehs/1/

This is because of the browser's event loop. All normal code runs, then its effects happen, then any `setTimout` functions run. So without `setTimeout` around the `classList.add` call, the box is added with its `background-color` being purple already. But with the `setTimout`, the box is added and then afterwards its `background-color` changes, causing the smooth transition.

A better solution is maybe to use css keyframes, see here for an implementation using them: https://codepen.io/ericwshea/pen/EyzZQg

So you can specify in css something like `animation: color-change 0.25s;` on the element you add in and also

```
@keyframes color-change {
    from {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    to {
        background-color: purple;
    }
}
```

in the css body.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I'm aware of the animation method. In this situation, I'm hinging a lot of the functionality on the behavior of the transition and this is just an edge case. In my mind it makes more sense to just use this method, rather than maintaining an animation along with a transition.

Comment: Yep makes sense to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try "onload". it works here. I only added extra CSS b/c I had nothing better to do.

```js
let DOM = document.createElement('div');

DOM.classList.add('box');

document.body.appendChild(DOM);

onload = ()=>DOM.classList.add('purple');
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  
  background-color: blue;
 
  transition: all 10s cubic-bezier(0.3, 5, 0.5, -2);
}

.box.purple {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: rotate(1080deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can't believe I didn't think of this, so simple.